# Error in using/installing v.digit: GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis

When I wanted to edit a shapefile in GRASS I got this message:

> Unable to start wxGUI vector
>   digitizer. Do you want to start TCL/TK
>   digitizer (v.digit) instead?
>
> Details: No module named
>   grass6_wxvdigit

Therefore, as suggested in this link:
http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/wxpython-gui-and-v-digit-td3019439.html and
https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass/trunk/gui/wxpython/README - 6. VECTOR
DIGITIZER I have been trying to compile/install vdigit component. I could
install GRASS with C++ (--with-cxx), Python (--with-python) and wxWidgets
(--with-wxwidgets) support. But in the next step when I change to the
directory "cd gui/wxpython/vdigit" and run make I get the following error:

```
..............
cats.cpp:456: error: ‘Vect_rewrite_line’ was not declared in this scope

cats.cpp:461: error: ‘G_debug’ was not declared in this scope
cats.cpp:467: error: ‘Vect_destroy_line_struct’ was not declared in this scope
cats.cpp:468: error: ‘Vect_destroy_cats_struct’ was not declared in this scope

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [OBJ.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/_grass6_wxvdigit.so] Error 1
```

I use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with GRASS 6.4.1svn. I tried installing `python-dev`,
`python2.6-dev` packages as suggested in many forums but the error
continued to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the GRASS mailing list:

This component has been replaced by Python'ized version in GRASS 6.5+. It
will be included in 6.4.2. No more need to use a C++ compiler.